# Is there any way to append array to list with arithmetic operator?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to append array to list, i can append with `.append()` but the case is to append with `+=`

getting this error **ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (28,28)** while executing below code

```
unique_labels = list(set(y))
images = []
for l in unique_labels:    
    idx = np.where(y == l)[0]
    idx = idx[np.random.permutation(len(idx))[:10]]    
    for i in idx:
        images += x[i]
```

Comment: What is `x`????

Comment: x is list of images, i'm trying to get images based on index

Comment: Fleshing out the example code so it is self contained (eg: include initialization of x) would help convey the intent.  If you're just trying to take an element from x (which is an image) and put it into images, can you use images.append(x[i]) or images += [x[i]]?

Comment: In `[] + np.arange(10)`, the array controls the action.  It turns the `[]` into an array, hence the broadcasting error.  `alist += [np.arange(10)]` is the same as `alist.append(np.arange(10))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming `x[i]` is a numpy `array` (one of the many `list` items in `images`):**

If you want images to be a `list` of numpy `array`s, and , `images.append(x[i])` and `images += [x[i]]` will both work, as @Andrew has commented.

Note it should be `images += [x[i]]` instead of `images += x[i]`. For illustration, suppose `images` is `[<object 0>, <object 1>, ..., <object n-1>]`. To add `<object n>` to `images`, you should use

```
images = [<object 0>, <object 1>, ..., <object n-1>] + [<object n>]
```

instead of

```
`images = [<object 0>, <object 1>, ..., <object n-1>] + <object n>`
```

where the former can be shortened to `images += [<object n>]`, of course.

If you want `images` to be a `list` of `list`s that have been converted from numpy `array`s, call `.tolist()` before adding `x[i]` to `images`, i.e.

```
images += [x[i].tolist()]
```